# Synchronizing pc-clock occasionally by Powershell and W32tm if time difference -gt 10 sec?

Tags: powershell, start-process

once and a while my prg running at a quite high cpu-time consumption.
After that the pc-clock could differ up to 10 sec despite I sync. the pc-clock with the internet-time twice a day.

Now I want to sync. the pc-clock if the time differs more than (e.g.) 2 sec. and I'd like to use:

```
     PS C:\Windows\system32> w32tm /stripchart /computer:us.pool.ntp.org /dataonly /samples:5
     Tracking us.pool.ntp.org [50.7.72.4:123].
     Collecting 5 samples.
     The current time is 08.08.2014 08:35:44.
     08:35:44, -00.1019929s
     08:35:47, -00.1082726s
     08:35:49, -00.1077418s
     08:35:51, -00.1082350s
     08:35:53, -00.1007278s
```

My problem how can my powershell script can receive the time differences from the w32tm?
Then of course I can check the difference and do:

```
     start-process w32tm /resync
```

For a millisecond the console appears but for sure the resync must fail as I do not start w32tm as admin yet - which causes an access not allowed-error.

Thanks in advance!

Fooling around I fond the solution - surprisingly easy:

```
      $x = w32tm /stripchart /computer:us.pool.ntp.org /dataonly /samples:5 | Out-String
      $x
```

As I cannot answer my own question here now my solution.
Once and a while high cpu-usages causes the pc-clock to run too fast and I have time sensitive programs that need to know the exact time.
On the other hand I can't define the exact time-stamp(s) of Win 7's time-sync (only every x seconds) which might cause a time change right when I do not want it.
So I programmed this solution which is fine for me but can be improved as
1) the time of the check and sync. are hard coded: always at Min 12 or 42 and Sec. 27 and
2) it must run as Administrator as other wise the time-sync fails with Error 0x80070005 => access denied.

Anyway for those who might be interested:

```
        # http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773263%28v=ws.10%29.aspx
        function chkSync { param([bool]$sync=$true)
            $x = w32tm /stripchart /computer:ptbtime2.ptb.de /dataonly /samples:5 | Out-String
            $y = $x.Split("`n")
            $c = 0
            $n = 0
            foreach( $a in $y ) {
                $z = $a.Split(",")
                if ( $z[1] -match '([\d\.\-\+]+)' ){
                    $b = [double]$matches[1]
                    $c += $b; $n++
                }
            }
            if ( $n -gt 0 ) {
                $d = $c/$n
            } else { $d = 0 }

            if ( $sync -and $d*$d -gt 1.0 ) { # instead of [Math]::Abs 
                Write-Host (get-date).ToString('HH:mm:ss') "bef. sync.:" $d.ToString('f3') "start sync. now"
                $s = w32tm /resync | Out-String
                Write-Host $s # Error 0x80070005 => access denied: run as adimnistartor!!
                chkSync $false
            } else {
                # every 30 min at 12:47 -or 42:47
                $slp = [int]$(1800 + 747 - ((((get-date).Minute)%30)*60 + $((get-date).Second)))
                Write-Host (get-date).ToString('HH:mm:ss') "avg. delay:" $d.ToString('f3')` 
                           "next check:" $($(get-date).AddSeconds($slp)).ToString('HH:mm:ss')
            }
            Start-Sleep -s $slp
        }

        do { chkSync } while ( $true )
```

Comment: Put results of the first command in an array of strings -> extract the diff values -> add together and divide by sample size -> you will have your time difference.

Comment: Why don't you simply enable and configure the NTP client? The policy settings described [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/nepapfe/archive/2013/03/01/it-s-simple-time-configuration-in-active-directory.aspx) can be made with a local policy as well.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers: As far as I understood NTP-Clinet it does not more than the Windows 7 automatic internet time sync defined in  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters. I already defined that (s.a.) to sync twice a day but I still get 10 sec difference.

Comment: You should be able to change the interval to something shorter than 12 hours.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers Of course I tried twice a day but it wasn't enough. See the add of my question: reason and solution.